# How to rearrange CharacteristicPolynomial[ ] terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a symbolic matrix A, which I need to find the characteristic polynomial, then order the polynomial in greatest-to-least form. (Ultimately to find the matrix inversion via Cayley-Hamilton method).

Orders from least-to-greatest:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* Input Matrix *)
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

cp = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x], x]
cl = CoefficientList[cp, x]
```

Using TraditionalForm[ ] does nothing?:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* Input Matrix *)
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

cp = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x], x] // TraditionalForm
cl = CoefficientList[cp, x]
```

This method won't allow CoefficientList[ ] to function properly:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* Input Matrix *)
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

cp = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x], x] // 
  PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &
cl = CoefficientList[cp, x]
```

From another answer on polynomial rearranging, also prevent CoefficientList[] from working:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* Input Matrix *)
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

c0 = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x], x] 
cx = CoefficientList[c0, x] x^Range[0, Exponent[c0, x]]
cp = Replace[Reverse@cx, List[x__] :> HoldForm[Plus[x]]]
cl = CoefficientList[cp, x]
```

I've tried other method outlined in past answers, but none seem to work with CoefficientList[ ] ? What gives?

Answer (score 2):

> Using TraditionalForm[ ] does nothing?:

Need to use `ParameterVariables`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

vars = {a, b, c, d};
(*Input Matrix*)
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
cp = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x], x]
TraditionalForm[cp, ParameterVariables -> vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html